# Why won't my Bootstrap 3 button icons display?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Basically, I am trying to display around 5 buttons, and I require 4 of them to have icons.

I have included the following link within the `head` of my document

```
<link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Although, the buttons are just showing with the correct style, and no icon next to them.

Here is the code for my buttons

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-info btn-large"><i class="icon-white icon-home"></i> Home</a>
<a href="#" class="btn btn-info btn-large"><i class="icon-white icon-info-sign"></i> About</a>
<a href="#" class="btn btn-info btn-large">FAQ <i class="icon-white icon-question-sign"></i></a>
<a href="#" class="btn btn-info btn-large">Learn <i class="icon-white icon-check"></i></a>
```

Within my bootstrap folder, I have 3 other folders named `css`, `fonts` and `js`. There were all taken directly from the Bootstrap download.

I have tried also including some javascript files and other css files, but there was no change.

Comment: Which bootstrap version you are using?

Comment: @devo - The latest, 3.0

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Bootstrap 3 has changed the icons to be in font format using the [Glyphicons Halflings](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#glyphicons) set.

You now need to use a base class of `glyphicon` followed by the class of the specific glyphicon you want to use (see the link for a complete list):

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span>
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use span instead of i,

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span>
```

Check this http://getbootstrap.com/components/#glyphicons

Comment: The tag is not the problem. Actually, you gave the answer in a subjective way, but didn't explained it :)